# How can I retrieve list of outlook contacts using VSTO?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsto

I have created a VSTO project for outlook 2010 Using Visual studio 2010. I added below items to my project:

1. A Ribbon with a Button
2. A Windows Form

When the button is pressed by user, the form is showing. I want the form to show list of all contacts in outlook but I don't know how should I access contacts data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you going:

[How To: Get a list of Outlook contacts](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/27/get-outlook-contacts/)
[How To: Retrieve Outlook Contact items using Restrict method](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/21/outlook-retrieve-contact-items/)
[How To: Use Find and FindNext to retrieve Outlook Contact items](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/19/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-contacts/)